# Redirecting to Login Page Automatically without doing Action in Controller ASP.NET MVC when session expired

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know it's a common question but I'm really exhausted of searching a complete solution without success. I have done an attribute filter but this works only if the user interact with the application and I don´t want this, I want when session expired, automatically the browser load the login page. Maybe someone could show what code should I use in javasccript or html .... and the configuration that I should use in the web.config if necesary. Thanks in advance.

This is my actual attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class SessionExpireCustom : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "_authstatus"] == null)
            {
                string redirectTo = "~/Account/Login";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl))
                {
                    redirectTo = string.Format("~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl));
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectTo);
                    return;
                }

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
                return;
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

And in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
    <!--KiloBytes--> 
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>    
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Show us what you have already done? Like post code?

Comment: It´s done, I have edited the post but really I want to change the complete result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. You can refer. It makes count time after user last action, not first visit on site.

In _Layout, add this:

```
<script>
    //session end 
    var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout- 1; //when session end 1 minute before this code makes redirect

    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
    setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

    function SessionEnd() {
        window.location = "/Account/LogOff"; //Redirect to LogOff, and then redirect to Login 
    }
</script>
```

--You need to clear Session in LogOff method.

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{    
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: this works almost perfect, what about actions in the application that not reload the page, for example , ajax call from any DataTable?

Comment: @ThorPF: Could you clarify more the requirement?

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for your time, I really appreciate but I just want to know if for reset the timer when the user make some action in any control of the view (the _layout it's not reloaded again), I need to reset the timer again each time in the code of the control event?

Comment: @ThorPF: Yeah, my friend. I think you're right. Need to reset in each view that you want. I don't have any different solutions better this time :))

Comment: Thank you very much, don't worry about it, still is a good solution that I didn't know it!!